# MongoDb : Cannot connect database on Docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I use the following `docker-compose.yml` to build a MongoDb database in a Docker container:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MONGODB_USERNAME: user
      MONGODB_PASSWORD: pass
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: social-network-db
volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

Then I restarted the container and try to connect database via MongoDb Compass app by using these values:

[Connection parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUdYK.png)

So, what is wrong and why I cannot connect to my MongoDb database? If you have some suggestion regarding to a`docker-compose.yml` parameter or creating used while building container, please inform me.

Comment: Does anybody else compose MongoDB on a Docker container?

Comment: You don't seem to have actually included the connection parameters you're using in the question.  Can you replace the link with the actual database settings you're using?  Can you also include your own application code that's trying to make the connection, and the text of the error you're getting?